# What is $(L^2(M), H^1_0(M))_{\frac 12}$ on a smooth manifold with boundary?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, smooth-manifolds, sobolev-spaces, interpolation-spaces

Let $M$ be a smooth compact manifold. If $M$ is closed, we have that the interpolation space
$$(L^2(M), H^1(M))_{\frac 12}=H^{\frac 12}(M)$$
(see Taylor's book on PDE for example). Suppose $M$ has a boundary. Then what is
$$(L^2(M), H^1_0(M))_{\frac 12}?$$
Is it some sort of Lions-Magenes space with a nice characterisation? A reference would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: You already mention Lions-Magenes. Have you looked at their book? If you do, you will find out about a space called $H^{1/2}_{00}$.